# Sql Update Count Details after grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have multiple tables in my SQL Server database.

I have one table say `Table A` which has fields like `dispatch,filename,`etc.

The second table say `Table B` has `filedetails` like `filename, dispatchcount, totalcount` etc.

There are many other fields in both tables but not relevant to this question.

Requirement is :

I want to update `Table B` dispatch count after grouping `Table A` customers where dispatch is Y.

As I want to update the Table B using the result of grouping should I create a temp Table of the result or please guide:

Query:

```
update Collation_Data set Dqty=T.count1 
from (select [collation_code],count(1) as 'count1'
FROM  [Tatkal].[dbo].[Tatkal_Merge] T 
where Dscan='Y'
group by [collation_code]) where srno=T.[collation_code]
```

Comment: Add sample table data, both before and after the update.

Comment: What jarlh said. But generally speaking, sounds like what you need is something like a trigger.

Comment: Your subquery needs an alias.

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server, you can use a `join` with an aggregation query.  I want to point out that you should use `left join` if you want to update *all* rows in `collation_data`, even those with no matches:

```
  update c
     set c.Dqty = cm.cnt 
  from Collation_Data c left join
       (select collation_code, count(*) as cnt
        from [Tatkal].[dbo].[Tatkal_Merge] m
        where Dscan = 'Y'
        group by collation_code
       ) cm
       on c.srno = cm.collation_code;
```

You can also do this with a correlated subquery:

```
update Collation_Data c
    set Dqty = (select count(*)
                from [Tatkal].[dbo].[Tatkal_Merge] m
                where m.Dscan = 'Y' and m.collation_code = c.collation_code
               );
```

This can be quite efficient with an index on `Tatkal_Merge(collation_code, Dscan)`.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to update the Table B using the result of grouping should I create a temp Table of the result or please guide

```
   update c
     set c.Dqty=T.count1 
    from Collation_Data  c
    join
    (select [collation_code],count(1) as 'count1'
    FROM  [Tatkal].[dbo].[Tatkal_Merge] 
    where Dscan='Y'
    group by [collation_code])t
     on c.srno=T.[collation_code]
```